# Что делать, если xmltojson крашится, найдя title="text<text>"?

Tags: python, json, регулярные-выражения, xmltojson

Пытаюсь понять, как можно обойти ошибку.
Парсинг страницы, получаю пригодный для `xmltojson` `outer html` страницы.
Обычно оно прокатывает - парсит в пригодный для дальнейшего `json.loads()` формат.

Но столкнулся с внезапной проблемой - на странице встретился подобный код:

```
<h1 class="the_class"><a href="/the_link.html" title="The title is <So important>">And some text here</a></h1>
```

Внимание на `title`:

```
title="The title is <So important>"
```

Узрев в `title` столь любимые им `<...>` он старательно крашнулся с сообщением, что мой xml `not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 67`.

Возможно ли как то обойти такое без выпиливания `title`?

PS Пробую написать более-менее универсальный regex чтобы выпилить `title` если в нем есть `<...>`: `r'title=".*<.*>.*"'` вроде неплохо работает, хмм.

Comment: `re.sub(r'\stitle="[^"]*"', lambda x: x.group().replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;"), text)`